# Count zero rows in 2D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

How do you count the amount of zero rows of a numpy array?

```
array = np.asarray([[1,1],[0,0],[1,1],[0,0],[0,0]])
```

-> has three rows with all zero's, hence should give 3

Took me sometime to figure out this one and also couldn't find an answer on SO

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could also leverage the "truthiness" of non-zero values in an array.

```
np.sum(~array.any(1))
```

i.e., sum the rows where none of the values in said row are truthy (and hence are all zero)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `np.all` if you're sure that the rows will have all zeros.

```
 # number of rows which has non-zero elements
In [33]: sum(np.all(arr, axis=1))
Out[33]: 2

# invert the mask to get number of rows which has all zero as its elements
In [34]: sum(~np.all(arr, axis=1))
Out[34]: 3
```

Comment: This is incorrect for cases where a row contains at least one zero but not all zeros.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

array = np.array([[1,1],[0,0],[1,1],[0,0],[0,0]])

non_zero_rows = np.count_nonzero((array != 0).sum(1))   # gives 2
zero_rows = len(array) - non_zero_rows                  # gives 3
```

Any better solutions?